# Spacing between navbar and first section

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I start to scroll down, the section **home** moves down and in between is a weird space which I don't know how to get rid of.

Any tips on how to fix this problem?

```js
//header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});


//
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 4000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Navigation */

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 32px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Smart Navbar / weiß wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */

#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}


/* Smart Navbar Ende */


/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */

#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* fixed nav Ende */

#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}

#Home {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#UberUns {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Aktionen {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Terminvereinbarung {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Infos {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */

.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* loader Ende */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>OptikTack</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="body">
      <div id="navbar">
        <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
        <ul>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#UberUns">Wir über uns</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Infos">Infos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="spacer"></div>
      <section id="Home" class="section">
        <p>Home</p>
      </section>
      <section id="UberUns" class="section">
        <p>section 2</p>
      </section>
      <section id="Aktionen" class="section">
        <p>section 3</p>
      </section>
      <section id="Terminvereinbarung" class="section">
        <p>section 4</p>
      </section>
      <section id="Infos" class="section">
        <p>section 5</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader-wrapper">
    <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(window).on("load", function() {
      $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $('a').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is creating a margin-top when you scroll down

try add:

```
#Home {
   margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I found a couple of issues.

```
if(st > navTop ){
    $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
    $('.section:eq(0)').css({'margin-top':navHeight});//fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
}
```

`st` is defined to be the current scrolling position of your browser.

This is in your scrolling code, meaning as soon as `st` is bigger than navTop, it will set margin-top to navHeight. But the issue is that a little bit up you defined navTop as followed: `var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;`

navTop is always 0. Meaning that whenever you scroll any amount it will add the margin-top. I'd start there with finding your problem.

Andrea's solution is but a solution for a problem that you introduced yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try add:

```
#Home {
       margin-top: 0 !important;
    }
```