# Fixed page header overlapsing anchors on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I click on any of my anchor links my header is **overlapsing** the actual content of the section. Is it possible to have it move the top of the section?
I've been looking for some solutions already but they're not working out for me.

I tried to add an anchor class to the sections and I also tried scroll-margin-top but it didn't quite work out.

```
//header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
    
var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
var windowH = $(window).height();

$('.section').height(windowH);

$(document).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    //for the nav bar:
    if(st > navTop ){
        $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
        $('.section:eq(0)').css({'margin-top':navHeight});//fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    }else{
        $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
        $('.section:eq(0)').css({'margin-top':'0'});
    }
    
    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
        if(st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight  <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()  ){
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
            
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
            // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('a[href="#'+id+'"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
            //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
        }
        
    });
    
});
    
});
//
```

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 4000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* Navigation */
ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 32px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */
#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}

/* Smart Navbar Ende */

/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */
#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* fixed nav Ende */

/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
*/
#Home {
   margin-top: 0 !important;
   border: solid;
   height: 1000px;
}

#UberUns {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Aktionen {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Terminvereinbarung {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#Infos {
  height: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */
.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* loader Ende */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#UberUns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <a id="top"></a>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="Home" class="section">
          <div>

          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- UberUns section -->
        <section id="UberUns" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 2</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Aktionen section -->
        <section id="Aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 3</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="Terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 4</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Infos section -->
        <section id="Infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(window).on("load", function() {
        $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
      });

    </script>
    <script>
      $('a').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please in your css code:
I just added top:0 to your navbar code and added margin-top to the next element in html, which is the section. I don't think the spacer div is necessary.

```
#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 1280px;
}

body {
margin-top: 128px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately :| But thank you anyways!

Comment: Sorry the margin-top had to be given to the body element not section. (I edited my answer) Please see this codepen. https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/xxOzqbd

Comment: This is a good solution and I'm grateful for you help. The only thing bothering me ist the gap between the sections. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot remove the the margin-top css property in codepen. Please check again.

Comment: This fixed where the section home starts but is there a way to fix where the other sections start? Otherwise great solution, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the problem with other sections

Comment: I'm sorry for asking the question not clear enough. My problem is that when you click for example on "Aktionen" you don't start at the beginning of the section. A small part of the section and of it's content is still overlapped by the header

Comment: I understand now. Please give me a few minutes and I will fix that as well

Comment: I think I found something. My only issue now is that my sections disappeared/are off screen. https://jsfiddle.net/bdwgk10f/224/

All I did was adding position relative and top 80px / 128px to all the sections