# Vertical aligning the logo in navbar not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to vertical align the "logo" to the navbar.
I would like it to be centered in the normal state and in the collapsed state.

I tried a few possible solutions but nothing seemed to work so far.
I tried adding different position types and I tried it with margin top and bottom 50% for example.
There's probably a very simple way to all this.

https://jsfiddle.net/qb0dj3yp/90/

Thanks in advance!

```
//header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});



//
```

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}

/* Navigation */
#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#logo {
  height: 128px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}

/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */
#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}

/* Smart Navbar Ende */

/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */
#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* fixed nav Ende */

/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/
#Home {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#UberUns {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */
.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* loader Ende */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
      <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <a href="#Home" id="logo"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#UberUns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- body -->
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="Home" class="section">
          <div>

          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- UberUns section -->
        <section id="UberUns" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 2</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Aktionen section -->
        <div id="reference"></div>
        <section id="Aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 3</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="Terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 4</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Infos section -->
        <section id="Infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(window).on("load", function() {
        $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
      });

    </script>
    <script>
      $('a').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your JSFiddle to use `display: flex` and `align-items: center`
https://jsfiddle.net/xv29r1sm/

You should give https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ a read :)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Taking all the advice I can get. I'm very new to this :)

Comment: But now the links in the navbar are on the left side. How do I fix that?

Comment: `float` properties do not apply to `flex` display items. You will need to use something like `justify-content: space-between` to pull the unordered list to the right of the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto` is your friend here. Apply this to the child div. Also check out usage of flex box

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds stupid but what exactly is a child div and what exactly does flex box mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want,

From the css section, search for **#navbar.shrink img** .

From there remove this line :
**margin-top: -30px;**

or just comment it like this :
/* margin-top: -30px; */

Now it should center vertically. Thats because the margin-top attribute will drag the image farther to the top which is not needed in your case.

```js
    //header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});



//
```

```css
    @charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}

/* Navigation */
#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#logo {
  height: 128px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */
#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}

/* Smart Navbar Ende */

/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */
#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  /*margin-top: -30px;*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* fixed nav Ende */

/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/
#Home {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: darkred;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#UberUns {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#Infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */
.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* loader Ende */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
      <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <a href="#Home" id="logo"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#UberUns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#Infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- body -->
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="Home" class="section">
          <div>

          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- UberUns section -->
        <section id="UberUns" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 2</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Aktionen section -->
        <div id="reference"></div>
        <section id="Aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 3</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="Terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 4</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Infos section -->
        <section id="Infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>



      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(window).on("load", function() {
        $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
      });

    </script>
    <script>
      $('a').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```