# Why is my anchor behaving differently after I click it the second time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I load up the website and click on *Wir über uns* it doesn't scroll down as much as when I click the button again (after scrolling up). It should scroll down to the start of the section and the picture in the first section should not be visible when it scrolls you down to the second section (like it does when you click it a second time)

https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/z2dLnfca/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- body -->
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="home" class="section">
          <div>
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- UberUns section -->
        <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 2</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Aktionen section -->
        <div id="reference"></div>
        <section id="aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 3</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 4</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Infos section -->
        <section id="infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>
```

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}

/* Navigation */
#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */
#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}

/* Smart Navbar Ende */

/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */
#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: auto;
}

/* fixed nav Ende */

/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/
#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#impressum {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */
.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }

  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* loader Ende */
```

```
//header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});



//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page is first loaded you have a negative margin of set on `#home`

```
#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}
```

When you start scrolling you change this margin. However you do not reset the margin to `-80px` when scrolling back to the top again which will result in you getting different result when the page first loaded and the second time you click the button.

Comment: @JannisN Another tip could be looking into using [position:sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) instead of fixed. It's very conveinient and you don't have to work with padding or margin to fix the page once you start scrolling. Note however that there might be some browser combatability issues with it.

Comment: Is it as simple as just replacing fixed with sticky? Is there anything big that I have to change?

Comment: @JannisN You need to remove your negative margins and top values and change a few other things. I edited your JS-fiddle here and added comments saying remove this/add this to what you need to change https://jsfiddle.net/o28dwzkb/1/

Comment: This seems quite simple and works great! Thank you very much! Can I move up the ```home``` somehow too? When I click the home button it doesn't really take me to the very top of the page.

Comment: The navbar seems to be glitching out when you scroll down just a tiny bit. It starts to shake for some reason. here's my jsfiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/3xk6azr9/8/