# anchor not scrolling to the very top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When you click on *home* you don't get scrolled to the very top. There is still a bit that you have to scroll manually. How can I set home to the top?

Could be using `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed` a better option?

If so how do I correctly replace the state of my navbar?

```js
// header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}


/* Navigation */

#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */

#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}


/* Smart Navbar Ende */


/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */

#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: auto;
}


/* fixed nav Ende */


/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/

#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 426px 426px 450px;
  grid-template-rows: 500px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ". .";
}

#impressum {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  height: 500px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#datenschutz {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}


/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */

.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* loader Ende */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>OptikTack</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="body">
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav id="navbar">
        <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
        <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png"></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
          <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- body -->
      <div id="spacer"></div>
      <!-- home section -->
      <section id="home" class="section">
        <div>
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild">
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- UberUns section -->
      <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
        <div>
          <p>section 2</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Aktionen section -->
      <div id="reference"></div>
      <section id="aktionen" class="section">
        <div>
          <p>section 3</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
      <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
        <div>
          <p>section 4</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Infos section -->
      <section id="infos" class="section">
        <div>
          <p>section 5</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <footer>
        <div id="impressum">
          <h3>Impressum</h3>

          <h4>
            Optik Tack GmbH
          </h4>
          <p>
            <!-- Icons von https://tablericons.com/ -->
            <!-- map Icon -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-map-pin" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="11" r="3" />
                <path d="M17.657 16.657l-4.243 4.243a2 2 0 0 1 -2.827 0l-4.244 -4.243a8 8 0 1 1 11.314 0z" />
              </svg> Mozartstraße 37 <br> 73430 Aalen <br>
            <!-- phone Icon -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-phone" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <path d="M5 4h4l2 5l-2.5 1.5a11 11 0 0 0 5 5l1.5 -2.5l5 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2a16 16 0 0 1 -15 -15a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2" />
              </svg> Tel.: 07361/123451 <br>
            <!-- at Icon -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-at" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4" />
                <path d="M16 12v1.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 5 0v-1.5a9 9 0 1 0 -5.5 8.28" />
              </svg> info@optik-tack.de <br>
            <!-- bookmark Icon -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-bookmarks" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <path d="M13 7a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12l-5 -3l-5 3v-12a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h6z" />
                <path d="M9.265 4a2 2 0 0 1 1.735 -1h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12l-1 -.6" />
              </svg> www.optik-tack.de
          </p>

          <p>
            Geschäftsführer: Anton Tack <br> Amtsgericht Aalen <br> Handelsregister Nr. XXX000XXX, <br> Finanzamt Aalen <br> USt.IdNr.: DE10111011 <br>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="datenschutz">
          <h3>Datenschutz</h3>
          <h4>Datenschutzhinweise</h4>
          <p>gemäß EU-Datenschutz-Grundverordnung (DSGVO)</p>
        </div>
        <div id="socialmedia">
          <!-- Instagram Icon -->
          <a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-instagram" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <rect x="4" y="4" width="16" height="16" rx="4" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3" />
                <line x1="16.5" y1="7.5" x2="16.5" y2="7.501" />
              </svg></a> <br>
          <!-- Facebook Icon -->
          <a href="#"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-facebook" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" />
              </svg> </a><br>
          <!-- Pinterest Icon -->
          <a href="#"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-brand-pinterest" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#607D8B" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                <line x1="8" y1="20" x2="12" y2="11" />
                <path d="M10.7 14c.437 1.263 1.43 2 2.55 2c2.071 0 3.75 -1.554 3.75 -4a5 5 0 1 0 -9.7 1.7" />
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" />
              </svg></a>
          <!-- Icons Ende -->
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Animation am Anfang vom Laden der Seite -->
  <div class="loader-wrapper">
    <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(window).on("load", function() {
      $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Animation Ende -->
  <!-- Smooth Scroll -->
  <script>
    $('a').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Smooth Scroll Ende -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is because you have apply 128px top margin to your HTML body.

Comment: I've post answer plz. accept it as answer.

Comment: There you go mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your CSS code

```
body {
  background-color: white;
/*  margin: 128px 0 0 0; */  comment this line or change to margin:0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it to this:

```
#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 128px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -128px;
}
```