# Why is my back to top button clickable in the whole row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a back to top button in my footer. It is clickable and it brings you back to the top of the page but the problem is that it is clickable in the whole row of my grid and I just don't know why that is.
I tried a few things already but can't come up with the right solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/arcoxs7z/124/

```js
// header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}


/* Navigation */

#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */

#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}


/* Smart Navbar Ende */


/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */

#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: auto;
}


/* fixed nav Ende */


/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/

#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 426px 426px 450px;
  grid-template-rows: 500px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ". .";
}

#impressum {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  height: 500px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#datenschutz {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}


/*
#socialmedia {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}*/

#backtotop {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: block;
}


/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */

.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* loader Ende */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container">
  <div class="body">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="navbar">
      <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
      <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png"></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- body -->
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <!-- home section -->
    <section id="home" class="section">
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild">
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- UberUns section -->
    <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 2</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Aktionen section -->
    <div id="reference"></div>
    <section id="aktionen" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 3</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
    <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 4</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Infos section -->
    <section id="infos" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 5</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <div id="impressum">
        <h3>Impressum</h3>

        <h4>
          Optik Tack GmbH
        </h4>
        <p>
          <!-- Icons von https://tablericons.com/ -->
          <!-- map Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02y75n0W/map-pin.png" alt="mapicon" width="16" height="16"> Mozartstraße 37 <br> 73430 Aalen <br>
          <!-- phone Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/wjPXGNJW/phone.png" alt="phoneicon" width="16" height="16"> Tel.: 07361/123451 <br>
          <!-- at Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tJ5dSmtP/at.png" alt="aticon" width="16" height="16"> info@optik-tack.de <br>
          <!-- bookmark Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T29PwXkG/bookmarks.png" alt="bookmarkicon" width="16" height="16"> www.optik-tack.de
        </p>

        <p>
          Geschäftsführer: Anton Tack <br> Amtsgericht Aalen <br> Handelsregister Nr. XXX000XXX, <br> Finanzamt Aalen <br> USt.IdNr.: DE10111011 <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="socialmedia">
        <!-- back to top Icon -->
        <a href="#home">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hgtxV1Y/arrow-up-circle.png" alt="backtotopicon" id="backtotop" width="75" height="75">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="datenschutz">
        <h3>Datenschutz</h3>
        <h4>Datenschutzhinweise</h4>
        <p>gemäß EU-Datenschutz-Grundverordnung (DSGVO)</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Animation am Anfang vom Laden der Seite -->
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
</div>

<script>
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
  });
</script>
<!-- Animation Ende -->
<!-- Smooth Scroll -->
<script>
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
</script>
<!-- Smooth Scroll Ende -->
```

Comment: Your anchor forms with your parent element, rather than the child. You could also simply just give your anchor your specifications, and use the image as a background. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your margins make the **image** fill the container

```
#backtotop {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: block;
```

Put the margins on the link instead by moving the ID to the link

```
<a href="#home" id="backtotop">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hgtxV1Y/arrow-up-circle.png" alt="backtotopicon" width="75" height="75">
</a>
```

and center using text-align on the container

```
#socialmedia {
  /* background-color: lightgreen; */
  text-align:center;
}

#backtotop {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: block;
}
```

```js
// header Effekt beim scrollen

$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});

  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
  });
</script>
<!-- Animation Ende -->
<!-- Smooth Scroll -->
<script>
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 128px 0 0 0;
}


/* Navigation */

#navlinks {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  color: black;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Smart Navbar / weiß, wo man auf der Seite ist von https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697696/change-underline-of-active-nav-by-section */

#navbar.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#navbar li.active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f6bd60;
}


/* Smart Navbar Ende */


/* fixed Navigation von https://codepen.io/malZiiirA/pen/cbfED?css-preprocessor=none */

#navbar {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1.25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2.5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  height: 128px;
  transition: 0.32s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 1280px;
}

#navbar.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

#navbar li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: -30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar img {
  height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbar.shrink img {
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: auto;
}


/* fixed nav Ende */


/*
#spacer {
  height: 128px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}


  margin-top: 0 !important;
*/

#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#aktionen {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -3;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -4;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#infos {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -5;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 426px 426px 450px;
  grid-template-rows: 500px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ". .";
}

#impressum {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  height: 500px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#datenschutz {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}



#socialmedia {
  /* background-color: lightgreen; */
  text-align:center;
}

#backtotop {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: block;
}


/* Hover Effekt bei Navigation von https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover/blob/master/css/hover.css */

.hvr-sweep-to-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f6bd60;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active {
  color: white;
}

.hvr-sweep-to-top:hover:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:focus:before,
.hvr-sweep-to-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


/* Hover Effekt Ende */


/* Loader */

.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #242f3f;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* loader Ende */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="container">
  <div class="body">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="navbar">
      <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
      <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png"></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- body -->
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <!-- home section -->
    <section id="home" class="section">
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild">
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- UberUns section -->
    <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 2</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Aktionen section -->
    <div id="reference"></div>
    <section id="aktionen" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 3</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Terminvereinbarung section -->
    <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 4</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Infos section -->
    <section id="infos" class="section">
      <div>
        <p>section 5</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <div id="impressum">
        <h3>Impressum</h3>

        <h4>
          Optik Tack GmbH
        </h4>
        <p>
          <!-- Icons von https://tablericons.com/ -->
          <!-- map Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/02y75n0W/map-pin.png" alt="mapicon" width="16" height="16"> Mozartstraße 37 <br> 73430 Aalen <br>
          <!-- phone Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/wjPXGNJW/phone.png" alt="phoneicon" width="16" height="16"> Tel.: 07361/123451 <br>
          <!-- at Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tJ5dSmtP/at.png" alt="aticon" width="16" height="16"> info@optik-tack.de <br>
          <!-- bookmark Icon -->
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T29PwXkG/bookmarks.png" alt="bookmarkicon" width="16" height="16"> www.optik-tack.de
        </p>

        <p>
          Geschäftsführer: Anton Tack <br> Amtsgericht Aalen <br> Handelsregister Nr. XXX000XXX, <br> Finanzamt Aalen <br> USt.IdNr.: DE10111011 <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="socialmedia">
        <!-- back to top Icon -->
        <a href="#home" id="backtotop">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7hgtxV1Y/arrow-up-circle.png" alt="backtotopicon" width="75" height="75">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="datenschutz">
        <h3>Datenschutz</h3>
        <h4>Datenschutzhinweise</h4>
        <p>gemäß EU-Datenschutz-Grundverordnung (DSGVO)</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Animation am Anfang vom Laden der Seite -->
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
</div>


<!-- Smooth Scroll Ende -->
```

Comment: Did you just move ```id="backtotop"``` to the a href? Because when I do it my img is not centered agian.

Comment: See update. You can center the link using text-align on socialmedia div